# Venu décembre, nous aurons de la neige

Tags: indications-de-temps, participe-passé

In French there is the sentence type “Une fois venu décembre, nous aurons de la neige”.
My question: Would it be possible to say: “Venu décembre, nous aurons de la neige”?

Comment: Voir aussi la comparaison avec l'emploi particulier au subjonctif comme ds. _viennent les [prunes](http://www.littre.org/definition/prune)_, ou plus [généralement](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/venir/81409/difficulte), _viennent les beaux jours..._ etc.

Answer (score 4):

*Une fois venu décembre* est un complément circonstanciel de temps, la principale est *nous aurons la neige*.

On pourrait aussi dire, de manière plus longue :

> Une fois que décembre est venu, Une fois qu'est venu décembre ...

Simplifié, cela donne:

> Une fois décembre venu

L'inversion citée est possible mais moins courante:

> Une fois venu décembre, ...

Pour simplifier encore plus, on peut dire:

> Décembre venu, ...

Ce qui signifie: *une fois/après que/dès que décembre est venu*, ...

La même construction peut être employée avec un nom et un participe passé:

> Mes parents arrivés, le travail fini, ...

La forme inversée proposée seule *venu décembre*, n'est **pas correcte**.

L'inversion n'est possible qu'avec le début *une fois (que)*

Comment: L'inversion (« décembre venu ») ne me paraît pas naturelle, mais elle a quand même été [utilisée par Yourcenar](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ItbaCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT66&dq=%22venu+d%C3%A9cembre%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22venu%20d%C3%A9cembre%22&f=false).

Comment: D'ailleurs, pour reprendre l'exemple d'Hakim, « L'hiver venu » me semble plus naturel que « Venu l'hiver ». Diantre. Je ne sais pas.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem wrong to me. I think this sentence is as correct as yours

> Arrivé l'été, nous pourrons nous baigner